# Request Error when trying to download images from Netflix

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Ok, I'm new with python and I'm intended to learn a little bit about webscraping which is even harder for me since I don't know anything about Web, JS, HTML etc. My idea was to download some images available on the [netflix catalogue](https://netflix.com/br/browse/genre/839338). And that even works fine for the first 5 or 6 images

```
import requests, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.netflix.com/br/browse/genre/839338"
page = requests.get(url)
page.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)

img_element_list= soup.select('a img')
print(f'Images avalaible (?) : {len(img_element_list)} ')
quantity = int(input('How many images: '))

for c in range(quantity):
    name = img_element_list[c].get('alt')
    print('Downloading ' + name + ' image...')
    img_response= img_element_list[c].get('src')
    print('SCR: ' + img_response + '\n\n')
    
    img = requests.get(img_response)

    file = os.path.join('Images', name)
    img_file = open(file+'.jpg', 'wb')
    for chunk in img.iter_content(100000):
        img_file.write(chunk)
    
    img_file.close()
```

But in the end after the forth or fifth image's been downloaded, the scr for the subsequent images gets like this 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==' and then it raises this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1513 IRON\PycharmProjects\DownloadNetflixImg.py", line 20, in <module>
    img = requests.get(img_response)
  File "C:\Users\1513 IRON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\1513 IRON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\1513 IRON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\1513 IRON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 640, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "C:\Users\1513 IRON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 731, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=='
```

Comment: I encountered something like this on another website. The work around I had to do was to pull the json format found within the `<script>` tags and then dig into that data to pull out the img urls. Not sure if that will work in this case (I can;t access netflix from where I am), but that would be the first thing I would try.

Comment: What should I do then? I'm not familiar with all this and didn't get what I should do

Comment: my advice is since you're new to python and webscraping, to then practice on a more basic website. Find websites that aren't as dynamic or complex and work your way up to more complex sites like netflix